# Step-by-step how to create a yii CModel

Tags: model, yii

I'm trying to create a Yii CModel class so I can view the data in a filtered, sorted grid.

It shouldn't be too complicated but I can't for the life of me work out how to do this. I'm looking for a step-by-step instruction set of how to get it going but I can't find anything. :(

I do not want to use a database backend, so I'm extending CModel.

I've put some code below but I'm just not sure of what to do next. Where does the actual data go? It must go in an array or something?

Any help would be great.

I've put some code in below, if it helps. Here's my model:

```
class MyModel extends CModel{
    public $id,
           $attribute1,
           $attribute2,
           $attribute3;

    public function search(){
        $criteria = new CDbCriteria;

        $criteria->compare('id', $this->id);
        $criteria->compare('attribute1', $this->attribute1);
        $criteria->compare('attribute2', $this->attribute2);
        $criteria->compare('attribute3', $this->attribute3);

        return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
            'criteria' => $criteria,
        ));
    }

public function attributeNames(){
        return array(
            'id',
            'attribute1',
            'attribute2',
            'attribute3',
        );
    }
}
```

Here's my controller:

```
class MyController extends CController{

    public function actionIndex() {
        $model = new MyModel('search');

        $model->unsetAttributes();

        if (isset($_GET['MyModel'])){
            $model->setAttributes($_GET['MyModel']);
        }

        $this->render('index', array(
            'model' => $model,
        ));
}
```

And here's my view:

```
$this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbGridView', array(
    'type'=>'striped bordered condensed',
    'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
    'filter' => $model(),
    'columns'=>array(
        'id',
        'attribute1',
        'attribute2',
        'attribute3',
    )
));
```

Comment: If you don't want to use a database backend, then you can't use `CDbCriteria`. The `Db` part stands for database. Do you intend for this to use persistant storage of some kind? Where does the data you want to filter/sort originate? From a user input, other?

Comment: Hi @WillemRenzema! No, I do not intend to use it for persistent storage. I want the model to execute some formulae, whose inputs come from a set of CActiveRecord models. I want to tabulate the output of the formulae in the form of a Grid, preferably a TbGridView. Does that make sense? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Where do you want the data to go?  Why don't you want to use a database?

Comment: I don't want it to be saved anywhere. I just want it to be calculated and then output or a page. I don't want it to go into a database because its used once to display on the screen and then never used again. I thought I would need to put it in an array or something so that it would be picked up by the inherited methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are just using the data for a grid view, you can use [CArrayDataProvider](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CArrayDataProvider).

Comment: Great. Thank you. So where would I use this? I presume there would be a method that returned an instance of CArrayDataProvider?

Comment: Click on the link to the API for an example -- you would just pass an array instead of the DB raw result. Create the CArrayDataProvider object and use that as your data provider in your widget.

Comment: This won't work unless I override the search method in my model. Is this correct?